# Get content from iframe and print it in a div in real time

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

**Well, what's my problem?**

I'm doing a basic Rich Editor, what i need is a "live preview", get the content of the iframe and show it in a div

i have this:

```
<iframe name = "richEdit" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
<div id = "live-preview">/div>
```

I want to get the content of the iframe richEdit and show it in the "live-preview div" in real time but i don't know how.

That's all,

THANKS!

**EDIT :**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor()
    .on('froalaEditor.contentChanged', function (e, editor) {
      $('#preview').html(editor.html.get());
    })
  });
</script>
```

This is an example of what i want, i replaced the variables, change the function, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to code anything we could start on? And I suppose the `iframe` is created using a plugin... Which is it?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Updated :)

Comment: So the plugin is [FroalaEditor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)... But, in their example, I don't see any `iframe`. And... I don't get why you would need to recreate a "live preview" outside of it. **Sounds like unclear**.

Comment: No, i don't have any plugin... Well, how i explain? The iframe is replacing a textarea of a page, a "blog", i want to save that content in sql database and show it in every comment that an user do.
It's a... signature.

Comment: So you gave the id `froala-editor` to your `div` just by chance? It looks like you are using this : https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#contentChanged I would try : `$('#preview').html( $(this).html() );` But I didn't read the documentation... I know this plugin since 13 minutes now.

Comment: And I still don't get why you want to create a "preview div"... You can take the Froala content directly on user submit to save the text..

Comment: It's just for better design, but, yes, i'm going to do what you say.

Comment: Its not a question of doing what I say... It a question of explaining why you want to do this, It may be good reasons. And you'll have to show more code, so SO anwerers may reproduce the issue you have.